# simple if else statement is not working

Tags: php, if-statement

i need a simple if else check whether any data is inserted to search or not.

So i set the condition ----

if the input data is **less than 1** than it will show that the user should input some data to search. otherwise it will search the result.

But somehow this simple thing is not working for me.

Do anyone knows how to solve this problem. Thanks in advanced.

```
$query = $_POST['Search'];

$min_length = 1;

if (isset($query) && !empty($query)) {

    if (strlen($query) > $min_length){
    // Check whether if there is atleast 1 character to chearch

    // method to search .....
    echo($result);
} else {
    echo "Sorry you have to put some data to search";
}
```

this one always return the if statement it never go to the else statement.

i have also tried like so ---

```
    $query = $_POST['Search'];

    $min_length = 1;

        if (isset($query) && ! empty($query) ) {

            if(isset($query) > $min_length){
    // method to search .....
    echo($result);
    } else {
    echo "Sorry you have to put some data to search";
}
```

But this one always return the else statement.

Can anyone knows how to fix this problem.

Comment: explain `not working` - the 2nd code block problem is obvious (`isset` return truw or false, so its never greater than 1), but what happens when you try the 1st code block

Comment: `isset($query) && !empty($query) && strlen($query) > $min_length` - can be done with `!empty($query)` only.

Comment: Is `query` actually retrieving a value from `$_POST['name']`? Check with `var_dump($query);`

Comment: @b0s3 i have tried "!empty($query)" but it is searching when there is no data as well.

Comment: What? That can't happen. If `$query` is empty then it will never get inside the block with `!empty($query)` if there are no mistakes.

Comment: @IsakJohnsson: a general note: your indentation is not very consequent in the code you provided. Perhaps this is only in the question and not in your real code, but working **very** tidy with regard to indentation always pays. For instance, it would be easy to spot the missing `}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some issues with the checks. First, check whether the POST actually contains a field 'Search':

```
$query = isset($_POST['Search']) ? $_POST['Search'] : "";
```

(edit: changed the field name from `name` to `Search`)

then, just check for it's length:

```
$min_length = 1;
if (strlen($query) >= $min_length) {
    // do search here
    // and echo the result
} else {
    echo "Sorry you have to put some data to search";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed on **}** and here is working code for you:

```
$query = $_POST['name'];

        $min_length = 1;

        if (isset($query)) {
            if (strlen($query) > $min_length) {
                // Check whether if there is atleast 1 character to chearch
                // method to search .....
                echo "result";
            } else {
                echo "Sorry you have to put some data to search";
            }
        }else {
            echo "name not set.";
        }
```

Comment: No idea, i expect this is the correct answer. Though it could be condensed into one check `if(isset($_POST['name']) && strlen($_POST['name']) > $min_length){//query}else{//error}`

Comment: with this code you will still get an `undefined index: name` error generated when `$_POST['name']` does not exist. Its better to do the `isset` on the `$_POST` array value before trying to move it to `$query`. Hence the downvote. Others should reconsider their upvote.